# How do I share the contents of a file on stack exchange without taking up too much screen real estate?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

How do I post the contents of a file on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) without overwhelming readers with a "***wall of text***"?

I know what a minimal reproducible example is. I will provide the shortest file possible.

However, even when files are short, readers should read the main post before ever looking at the file contents.

The file contents might distract the reader.

The test-file contents are more for machine eyes than human ones, and you should read the test-file only after looking at everything else.

I want to include the contents of a text file into the question/posting in such a way that people can select, copy, and paste the text, without actually having to see it all on the screen.

#### File Contents (`df_events.csv`)

| ID | Name | Event Type | Event Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Mike | upgrade | 10/02/20 |
| 78 | Jane | upgrade | 9/18/20 |
| 12 | Mike | cancel | 10/30/20 |
| 12 | Mike | upgrade | 11/25/20 |
| 78 | Jane | cancel | 11/14/20 |

Is there someway to draw an HTML box, where the box is really small, but contains a lot of text? That is, the box contains more text than is visible on the display/monitor?

#### Code Blocks Require More Space (Screen Real Estate) than I would like

```
ID,Name,Event Type,Event Date
12,Mike,upgrade,10/2/2020
78,Jane,upgrade,9/18/2020
12,Mike,cancel,10/30/2020
12,Mike,upgrade,11/25/2020
78,Jane,cancel,11/14/2020
```

***Spoiler*** boxes are a thing... I guess. They still take more more screen real-estate than I would like.

> ID,Name,Event Type,Event Date
>  12,Mike,upgrade,10/2/2020
>  78,Jane,upgrade,9/18/2020
>  12,Mike,cancel,10/30/2020
>  12,Mike,upgrade,11/25/2020
>  78,Jane,cancel,11/14/2020

I sometimes post file contents on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/), then provide a link.
I hate doing that, because websites like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) have come and gone over the years. I don't want my question to have a link to a dead page.

Ideally, the file contents will only stop being accessible when my question is deleted, or ***stackexchange.com*** dies some years down the road.

Ideally, a stack overflow post would have a tiny box where people can click and copy the text without reading it all.

1. left-click
2. press `ctrl-a` (select all)
3. press `ctrl-c` (copy)
4. press `ctrl-v` (paste)

I would not mind a 4,000 character maximum or something.

Ideally, I would like users to be able to read the text after pasting it into a text editor, but not before-hand. That might sound like a prank, practical joke, or something, but trolling people is not my intention.

Comment: If the data is really crucial to your question, then it doesn’t really matter how much screen real estate it takes up, does it? Five CSV rows is just fine; some askers post way too much data, so post only what is necessary and it will be fine.

Comment: You could also post a few example rows and say that you need at least X similar rows to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't get any smaller. It does require clicking *Show code snippet* and then *Run code snippet* (if the data is really big), click the button and the text in texarea is on your clipboard.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740713/
// by Joel Harkes https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275832/joel-harkes
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
    var copy = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('copy');
        var text = document.getElementById('txt').value;
        if (e.clipboardData) {
            e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
        } else if (window.clipboardData) {
            window.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('copy', copy);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    window.removeEventListener('copy', copy);
}
```

```html
<button id='btn'>copy</button><br>
<textarea id='txt'>
ID,Name,Event Type,Event Date
12,Mike,upgrade,10/2/2020
78,Jane,upgrade,9/18/2020
12,Mike,cancel,10/30/2020
12,Mike,upgrade,11/25/2020
78,Jane,cancel,11/14/2020
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 7):

> I know what a minimal reproducible example is.
> I will provide the shortest file possible.

Despite appearances, SO is not a debugging site. Asking people to post a minimum reproducible example is actually a trick to get people to do their own debugging. If you think you *need* to post a long sample file, you have probably **not** got a minimum reproducible example. It means you need to do more debugging yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The best option might be to post a sample of the file you want in the question - not the whole thing, but enough to get the point across and put the rest on pastebin/ Google docs/whatever.

Bear in mind that not many people want to click on links anyway, so this might be the best way of attracting answers.